# How can I use C# replace to remove the string \" and replace with just the "

Tags: c#, html, string, replace, trim

I am trying to capture html from a page using a WYSIWYG editor that Im making where the user can play around with and change templates. I have managed to strip the html all but for one remaining hurdle in that I cannot seem how to work out how to remove \" and replace with just a ". My string is being written like:

```
<div class=\"row top20\">
```

where I would like it to be:

```
<div class="row top20">
```

I removed other parts of the string by doing:

```
string test = ownhtml.Replace(fake1T1, image1T1Uri).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Trim();
```

I have tried to chain

```
.Replace("\","").Trim();
```

But this gives an error as I know it is used for special characters in c# so I tried \ but this didnt work

Comment: Care to tell us *what* error it gives you when using that line?

Comment: Next time, post the entire error. Saying "It gives an error" means nothing *without* that error message. The error message **you would have gotten** would probably be a compilation error about un-escaped characters.

Comment: I have yet to solve my problem and I have edited my post in regards to the unescaped characters but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape the \ and the " in you replace statement

Try this:

```
.Replace("\\\"","\"").Trim();
```

This will escape the characters and resolve to

```
.Replace("\"",""").Trim();
```

Comment: Did not work though i totally get what you mean this is how i assumed it would work

Comment: Why did this not work? Did you get an error or did it just not replace what you wanted?

Comment: No error just didnt replace what i wanted. I also tried .Replace(@"\\","") just to try remove the \ but to no avail not sure maybe its a C# thing

Comment: If you are using the @ to escape it, you shouldn't need the double backslash you should just need one

Comment: also tried .Replace(@"\","").Trim(); but this doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has a similar problem I was able to solve using a stringbuilder and excluding this character:

```
StringBuilder campaignhtml = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < ownhtml.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ownhtml[i] != '\\') { campaignhtml.Append(ownhtml[i]); }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening in the debugger only. Upon persist the /n was removed